Python alternative to R interact_plo
Is there a python package that would mean-centre all continuous and reference-level all categorical variables not involved in the interaction so that predicted values in the interaction plot are more easily interpreted.
Thanks

Hi. You're asking your question in the wrong place, as this is not a website about programming, but about open data. I think you'll be more likely to get an answer either on https://stackoverflow.com or on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.
